# Pinterest sdk callback class error: cannot access Response class file for com.android.volley.Response not found

Tags: android, android-volley, pinterest, pdk

I am trying to integrate Pinterest for sharing blog/creating a pin. I am following [the official documentation](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/sdks/android/?), [tutorial1](https://blog.fossasia.org/share-images-on-pinterest-from-phimpme-android-application/) and [tutorial2](https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-pinterest-integration-and-login-tutorial/)  to integrate the Pinterest. 
But, the issue is when I try to authorize the user and pass `PDKCallback` object into the login method as shown below,

```
    pdkClient.login(this, scopes, new PDKCallback() {
            @Override
           public void onSuccess(PDKResponse response) {
                Log.d(getClass().getName(), response.getData().toString());
                //user logged in, use response.getUser() to get PDKUser object
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(PDKException exception) {
               Log.e(getClass().getName(), exception.getDetailMessage());
          }
        });
```

It shows me the following **compilation** error

> cannot access Response class file for com.android.volley.Response not found

Can anybody help me with this problem?

**Edit**

My pdk module gradle file is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
//    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
}
```

My app module build.gradle file's dependency is as follows

```
dependencies {

implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') 
 {
        transitive = true
    }

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.plattysoft.leonids:LeonidsLib:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'

    implementation project(':wScratchViewLibrary')
    implementation project(':linkedin-sdk')
    implementation project(':pdk')

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1'

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:4.33.0'
    implementation ('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.3.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'

    implementation "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.4.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.6.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/nineoldandroids-library-2.4.0.jar')

    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.cooltechworks:ScratchView:v1.1'
}
```

My PinterestApi class from which I try to access the login method of pdk.

```
package com.veriloginqr.android.sharing_apis;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.pinterest.android.pdk.PDKCallback;
import com.pinterest.android.pdk.PDKClient;
import com.pinterest.android.pdk.PDKException;
import com.pinterest.android.pdk.PDKResponse;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PinterestApi {

    private static final String appID = "my_app_id_i_wont_reveal";

    private PDKClient pdkClient;

    private Context context;

    public PinterestApi(Context context) {
        this.context=context;

        // Call configureInstance() method with context and App Id
        pdkClient = PDKClient.configureInstance(context, appID);

        // Call onConnect() method to make link between App id and Pinterest SDK
        pdkClient.onConnect(context);
        PDKClient.setDebugMode(true);

    }


    public void authorizeUser(){

        List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
        scopes.add(PDKClient.PDKCLIENT_PERMISSION_READ_PUBLIC);
        scopes.add(PDKClient.PDKCLIENT_PERMISSION_WRITE_PUBLIC);

        pdkClient.login(context,scopes,new PDKCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(PDKResponse response) {
                Log.d(getClass().getName(), response.getData().toString());
                //user logged in, use response.getUser() to get PDKUser object
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(PDKException exception) {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), exception.getDetailMessage());
            }
        });

    }

}
```

> **Note:** You can check the pdk source code [here.](https://github.com/Pinterest/Android-PDK/)

Comment: Did you add [the volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/) dependency to `build.gradle`?

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท yes, It is already there.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท Please check the edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the volley version from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 like this

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```

or I think you should be adding volley in your app’s build.gradle

Comment: I tried adding volley version 1.0.1 which was failed to resolve and I also tried to change to the latest version 1.1.1. but, Still the same error occurs

Comment: try adding `jcenter()` in your project's build.gradle file

Comment: everything seems good, please make sure that you have proper network connectivity

Comment: This is a compilation error. And network connectivity is also fine.

Comment: I think you should be adding volley in your app’s build.gradle

Comment: Finally, adding the volley in app's build.gradle file worked. Now, It does not show error. But it did not give the callback . Now,  what to do ?

Comment: does it not enter just the success callback or the failure one as well?

Comment: @NavneetKrishna It did not give any callback neither success nor callback

Comment: @NavneetKrishna I realized I just forgot to add the code inside `onActivityResult`. Now I am getting callback. (It is failure).

Answer (score 0):

Imports & codes seems fine. The issue seems to be not downloading the whole dependency nor, there was a problem when building which needs a rebuild-clean project.

The solution will be using the latest version:

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```

And making sure offline work not checked in the Settings.

Comment: I tried using latest verison of  volley 1.1.1 . but it also did not worked

Comment: Can you paste the other `Build.gradle` file from `app/build.gradle` to your question? I assume you might forget about something. Also, appcompat shouldn't be in your current `Build.gradle` And make sure about this line: `compile project(':pdk')` if you have already added it in: `app/build.gradle`. **Check [this file**](https://github.com/pinterest/android-pdk/blob/master/pdk/build.gradle) and [This](https://github.com/pinterest/android-pdk/blob/master/app/build.gradle).